# ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package color

Tags: r, rstudio

I am writing a chinese report by a R package of articles, there some errors occered, my code is as following:

```
title: "食品与生物实验设计与数据分析"
author:
  - xue
documentclass: ctexart
output:
  rticles::ctex:
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
classoption: "hyperref,"

#女士品茶的故事

那是20世纪20年代后期，在英国剑桥一个夏日的午后，一群大学的绅士和他们的夫人们，还有来访者，正围坐在户外的桌旁，享用着下午茶。在品茶过程中，一位女士坚称：把茶加进奶里，或把奶加进茶里，不同的做法，会使茶的味道品起来不同。在场的一帮科学精英们，对这位女士的“胡言乱语”嗤之以鼻。这怎么可能呢？他们不能想象，仅仅因为加茶加奶的先后顺序不同，茶就会发生不同的化学反应。然而，在座的一个身材矮小、戴着厚眼镜、下巴上蓄着的短尖髯开始变灰的先生，却不这么看，他对这个问题很感兴趣。
```

the error is the following:

> output file: food_and_secuty.knit.md
>
> ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package color.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> l.33 \hypersetup
>
> pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF 错误: pandoc document conversion failed
>   with error 43 此外: Warning message: 运行命令'"C:/Program
>   Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS
>   food_and_secuty.utf8.md --to latex --from
>   markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash
>   --output food_and_secuty.pdf --table-of-contents --toc-depth 2 --template "E:\R-3.2.5\library\rticles\rmarkdown\templates\ctex\resources\default.latex"
>   --number-sections --highlight-style tango --latex-engine xelatex'的状态是43  停止执行

Comment: Can you add the commands you are using that create the error - or are you clicking buttons in RStudio?

Comment: I click the button of knitr in Rstudio,the error above appeared.